# The footer is moving up in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Sometimes, the footer goes up in some pages.

So here is the page where I have the problem : 
[image: Image with moving footer]

And here is the page that comes just after, and with a normal footer :

[image: Image with normal footer]

I am using the package fancyhdr in my document :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am having this problem please, and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `footer` in latex is the fixed page area usually used for the page number, it is not the area used for footnotes. The `footmisc` package has a `bottom` option to place footnotes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX, can you tell what I'm suppose to do to fix it ??

Comment: @Sidahmed `fix` is the wrong word really as the footnote placement was an intentional design decision rather than a bug to be fixed, but anyway just add `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` to your document

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for using the word fix, just didn't found what to say.

Comment: @Sidahmed no need to apologise:-)